# Get smallest power of variable in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

In sympy I have laurent polynomials in several variables (e.g. x,y,...) and I need the smallest exponent of the expression.
e.g.

> expr = x**-3+y/x+2

The smallest power of x is -3 and the smallest power of y is 1. What I actually wish to do is normalize the laurent polynomial by multiplying by x^a y^b to obtain a non-laurent polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

This works for your example (returns `-3`), and believe it will work in general for any Laurent polynomial:

```
min((z.as_base_exp()[1] for z in expr.atoms(sympy.Pow)), default=1)
```

**Explanation**:
Extract the atoms from `expr` that are raised to powers other than 1.  Convert each atom to a `(base, exponent)` pair, discard the base, and return the smallest exponent value. Default to 1 in the event that `expr.atoms(sympy.Pow)` is empty.

---

**Edit**:
It should be noted that `atoms(*types)` will return *every* atomic object that is matched by `types`. so if `expr` looked like this:

```
x**2 + y + exp(x**(-2)) - 5/y
```

the result set will include `x**(-2)` since it matches `sympy.Pow`, and that may not be desirable in some cases. Since this question is specifically about Laurent polynomials, it shouldn't be a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
In [14]: expr = x**-3+y/x+2                                                                                                       

In [15]: expr                                                                                                                     
Out[15]: 
    y   1 
2 + ─ + ──
    x    3
        x 

In [16]: cancel(expr)                                                                                                             
Out[16]: 
   3    2      
2⋅x  + x ⋅y + 1
───────────────
        3      
       x       

In [17]: cancel(expr).as_numer_denom()                                                                                            
Out[17]: 
⎛   3    2         3⎞
⎝2⋅x  + x ⋅y + 1, x ⎠
```